# Filter data row using table.select

Tags: vb.net, datarow

I follow  [DataTable.Select Method[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataTable_Select_System_String_System_String_) to sort and order the table.  However I got the error "Syntax error: Missing operand after 'Number' operator." I searched the web and still cannot figure out what is wrong.  Would someone tell me how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
    Dim Table As DataTable = New DataTable
    Table.Columns.Add("Week Number", GetType(Integer))
    Table.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(Date))

    Dim newRow1 As DataRow = Table.NewRow()
    newRow1("Week Number") = 52
    newRow1("Date") = "1979, 12, 31"
    Table.Rows.Add(newRow1)

    Dim newRow2 As DataRow = Table.NewRow()
    newRow2("Week Number") = 1
    newRow2("Date") = "1980, 1, 3"
    Table.Rows.Add(newRow2)

    Dim expression As String = "Week Number =1"
    Dim sortOrder As String = "Date ASC"
    Dim foundRows As DataRow()
    foundRows = Table.Select(expression, sortOrder)
```

2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column name contains a space then you need to enclose the whole name inside square brackets to avoid confusing the parser

```
Dim expression As String = "[Week Number] =1"
Dim sortOrder As String = "Date ASC"
Dim foundRows As DataRow()
foundRows = Table.Select(expression, sortOrder)
```